# Using access tokens on Dockerfile to clone repository: RUN command error

Tags: bash, docker

In a Dockerfile, I'm trying to clone several Gitlab repositories that are specified in a file, one per line, using an access token passed as an environment variable set in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
COPY my-repos.txt my-repos.txt
RUN 'cat my-repos.txt | while read REPO; do git clone https://oauth2:$GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN@gitlab2.<domain>.com:16443/$REPO.git; done'
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: cat my-repos.txt | while read REPO; do git clone https://oauth2:$GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN@gitlab2.<domain>.com:16443/$REPO.git; done: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c 'cat my-repos.txt | while read REPO; do git clone https://oauth2:$GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN@gitlab2.<domain>.com:16443/$REPO.git; done'' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Running without quotes gives another error:

```
Cloning into 'ML_tools'...
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab2.<domain>.com:16443/<correct_repo>.git/'
The command '/bin/sh -c cat my-repos.txt | while read REPO; do git clone https://oauth2:$GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN@gitlab2.<domain>.com:16443/$REPO.git; done' returned a non-zero code: 128
```

The thing is, if I comment out the RUN line, build the image and enter the container, running manually the command works perfectly. The environment variable is correctly set. Is maybe some variable out of scope at build time?

Comment: You put the entire line in single quotes, so the shell interprets it as a single word.  Also remember that this line will show up in `docker history` as-is, so anyone who has a copy of the image will have your GitLab credentials; I'd recommend running any `git` operations outside of Docker before you start building your image (maybe even check the Dockerfile into the repository).

Comment: Yes, I was running with single quotes because without them also fails with a different error that I forgot to mention, my fault (see the updated question). I am aware of the security risks, this is just somethings I'm trying at home. I didn't see the way to, for example, build a repository in a volume at docker build time, as the volume is not mounted yet. Do you know the proper way to do it?

Comment: Your code doesn't belong in a volume at all.  If you need to copy data into a volume when the container starts up, you can look into an entrypoint wrapper script for it, but the first thing I'd try here is completely avoiding volumes.  (You can generally use a non-Docker development environment and then push the same code into an image for deployment.)

Comment: Also note that Docker provides mechanisms for injecting secrets into the build process without them getting embedded in the resulting image. See the documentation on [build secrets](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#new-docker-build-secret-information).

Comment: What I need is to install in the container some local python libraries that I usually install with "pip install -e", and I can clone them from repo or  copy them into container. Should this be done in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was declaring:

```
ARG GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

BEFORE the FROM statement and it has to be done AFTER it.